# Adopting bug tracking / project management software: To open source or not to open source?

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking

My manager has recently asked my team and I for our input about implementing a bug tracking / project management solution. From his perspective, he would like more visibility around where our projects actually are in the grand scheme of things as well as the ability to see some analysis on how bugs are being caught and addressed.

My old company, implemented [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) as a means to plan, track, and manage bugs. It worked great! However, my new company is a little more... how shall we say... averse- to implementing open source projects as our corporate solutions. There concerns are mainly concerning the amount of time we might spend maintaining and customizing the software to meet are needs.

They, management, are initially more in favor of a more "sturdy" product offering like Joel's [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/).

So, the question is-

- at what point does the flexibility
  and cost savings of implementing an
  open source solution get drowned out
  by the headache of maintainence and
  the creep of calls for constantly
  expanding functionality?
- Is there a
  clear line?
- And what can I say as a
  grunt to convince my managers of a
  [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)-like solution that won't
  end up being a nightmare for
  everyone?

Comment: I don't have the time to write a complete answer, but i'd go with Fogbugz on this one. The risk of advocating something to the wrong people is far too high. But you seem to be in favor of trac already.

Comment: @Peter Lindqvist: Please post answers as answers -- however brief -- so we can process them as answers.  Posting an answer as a comment is confusing and weird.  It doesn't matter that it's short, what matters is that answers are posted as answers so we can vote on them appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask:

> at what point does the flexibility and
>   cost savings of implementing an open
>   source solution get drowned out by the
>   headache of maintainence and the creep
>   of calls for constantly expanding
>   functionality?

Firstly, what maintenance? All the FOSS software I use just works - I certainly don't maintain it, any more than I maintain proprietory software. Of course, If I do spot a bug I'll report it and even try to fix it, but I don't *have* to do this.

Secondly, what calls for expanding functionality? You should only consider a FOSS solution if it meets all your needs. Once installed, you should no more consider expanding its functionality than you would for a proprietory solution, unless you want to, of course.

Comment: +1: If your process doesn't match the software, consider that it's possible that your process is broken.  Fixing your process is easier and cheaper than customizing software.

Comment: I second this. In practice, I have had to deal with JIRA, Spiceworks, Bugzilla and Redmine. They all work, each of them is geared to slightly different needs. After setting up the workflows and ensuring people follow them, why would one need expanding functionality for a bugtracking system?

Comment: I agree with your exandability comment and granted I might have exaggerated our need to expand functionality- my main concern is the initial setup and customization. When it comes to the exact time its going to take to setup it up i am ignorant- my last company implemented it before i came along. The other thing, is this is not that big of a concern for just one time- however, management wants a solution that can be implemented at several drastically different sites with relative ease.

Comment: I tried out Trac about 6 months or so ago, it didn't meet my personal needs, but I seem to recall the setup took me about 10 minutes, and I'd expect other FOSS bug trackers to be about the same. Of course, you need to factor in time to maintain users,  project info, etc. but that's equally true for proprietory solutions.

Comment: @ Neil Butterworth - Wow! 10 minutes! My old manager had told me his initial setup of Trac took him a couple days, granted that might have been due to his busier-than-average schedule, but he was no amateur. Thanks- that is very encouraging though.

Comment: If it had been a couple of days, I would have given up long before. It might have been 15 minutes, but we are talking of something of that order. Of course, I do have some understanding of networks, web servers etc.

Comment: BTW, if you are going to try out Trac see the http://bitnami.org/ site for very easy to install packages.

Answer (score 3):

In a lot of work-places all they really want is someone they can call up to fix problems if they arise, if you look at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommercialServices, you'll see there are a few companies who offer commercial support for Trac so that may help swing things that way.

Comment: I wasn't aware of commercial service providers for Trac- great advice! The only caveat is that my company is government-related and as such not many hosted solutions are allowed unless of course we are the ones' doing the hosting. Is there any commercial service provider that could help alleviate some of the potential obstacles with trac given that big restraint?

Answer (score 1):

The question has to be answered in the context of your company's culture, background, development environment etc.

Are they familiar with and comfortable with Open Source?

Are they using Microsoft technology or Java?

Are you paying for the software out of your salary or is the company going to pay for it? :)

Is your immediate manager paying for the software out of his salary? :)

How much credit will your company give you for saving them some money?

How much flak will you get if an open source solution fails?

*** I think if you meditate on the last 2 points, go ahead and spend the money for a better supported solution. If they are a Microsoft shop, just go with their bug tracking system. If not, go with something like FogBuz. If it is a bank, go with Remedy.

Now, if it was your own startup, then open source would make a lot of sense. If the company is very comfortable with open source, it might also make sense. However, it sounds like they aren't and that you are setting yourself up for trouble going with open source. If anything goes wrong (and it may have nothing to do with it being open source) then fingers will be pointed at you saying "it was an open source solution". The operative phrase is CYA - Cover Your Ass.

Comment: Another operative phrase is "Go with the flow". You said yourself "the management is initially in favor of a more sturdy product offering like Joel's FogBuz". Nothing in life is free and you generally get what you pay for. Go with the flow. If you confirm their intuition (and there are plenty of reasons why it might be a good decision) then it will be an easy sell. If you go against the flow, and you turn out to be wrong, fingers will be ponted.

Comment: sage advice- "go with the flow", thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is to some extent a string-lenght question, but here are my random thoughts:

- Just because a piece of software is commercial and backed-up by a support organization, it isn't hassle-free to install and set up.
- Compare the licensing cost with the time needed to set up (and maintain) an open-source solution. Will the open-alternative be functional in a day, week or month?
- The problem with scope creep is really a management problem.
- If you aren't really sure what you need, trying out an open alternative first is a great way of building experience in what functionality is essential to your organization.

Comment: I hadn't really considered that we don't necessarily have to move on something completely before making a decision- my manager might go for the idea of a trial run with Trac or a trial period of FogBugz.

Answer (score 0):

I also like Trac (I'm using it for a hobby project with a couple of friends) but I think FogBugz and several other commercial PM/bug tracking software packages are probably better. If management is willing to pay for a commercial solution, where's the problem?

Comment: Trying to save money is always one of there top priorities. So, it comes down to a cost/benefit analysis of are we actually going to be saving enough money (factor our sanity in there too) by using something like trac instead of something like fogbugz?